# What is msnodesqlv8 to node-mssql?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, node-mssql, msnodesqlv8

What is the relationship between https://www.npmjs.com/package/msnodesqlv8 and https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql?

The documentation is confusing and I can interpret it a few different ways.

Answer (score 6):

[msnodesqlv8](https://github.com/TimelordUK/node-sqlserver-v8)

> This library has full compatibility with MS SQL Server using an MS
> ODBC driver. Many functions e.g. open, query, connection pool,
> prepare, transactions, close will work with any ODBC compatible driver
> with its respective database.

mssql uses [Tedius](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious) which is:

> Tedious is a pure-Javascript implementation of the TDS protocol, which
> is used to interact with instances of Microsoft's SQL Server. It is
> intended to be a fairly slim implementation of the protocol, with not
> too much additional functionality.

So one is a wrapper around the official Microsoft supported ODBC driver, but requires installing that ODBC driver in your OS or container, while the other is a wrapper around a pure-Javascript TDS client so you can add it purely through NPM, but which is not an official Microsoft driver, even though there are some Microsoft/Github contributors.

You should expect that Tedius may lack support for the very latest TDS protocol versions and for some less-used features of the TDS protocol, and that you won't be able to open a Microsoft support case for any issues you find; those would go to the Github repo to be addressed by the community.

Comment: Adding to this already very good answer, an example of a limitation, mssql does not support windows authentication.

Comment: What ODBC drivers can msnodesqlv8 use and how do you specify it?  I have code which worked on a previous computer but now throws "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified" on my new computer and I can't find what driver to install or how to specify a driver ('ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' exists on the new computer)

Comment: You specify the driver in the "driver=" connection string attribute.  see eg: https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-odbc-driver-17-for-sql-server/